# How did Kakabhushundi see Ramayana and Mahabharata a different number of times?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, ramayana, rama

If life is defined as a cycle of 4 yugas (sata yuga, treta yuga,dwapara yuga and kal yuga) where they all occur in order infinitely, then how did Kakabhushundi witness the Ramayana lesser times (11 times) than the Mahabharat (16 times)? Doesn't the Ramayana (or the birth of Lord Ram) occur every treta Yuga and Mahabharata (or birth of Lord Krishna) occur every dwapara Yuga? If so, then how is the number of treta yuga less than the number of dwapara yuga when they all occur one after the other indefinitely?